# Memory leak after deleting template class

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

If I have the following class:

```
// ComponentMan.h
class ComponentMan
{
public:
    template<class T>
    void CreateComponent<T>()
    {
        T* temp = new T();
        delete temp; // Memory leak?
    }
}
```

- Does deleting temp cause a memory leak?
- Because the program doesn't know T's size?
- If so, how can I avoid it?

Comment: If it didn't know the object size, how could it have processed the `new` in the first place?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: You should make that an answer!

Comment: This has got nothing whatsoever to do with templates. This question is essentially just asking how `free` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At deletion time, the compiler does *not* know the size of the object pointed to by `temp`, but it doesn't need to know and hence there is no leak. For example:

```
struct T { int t; };
struct U : public T { int u; };
T * temp = new U();
delete temp; // compiler doesn't know whether it's dealing with a T or a U
```

Forget about C++ for now, and simply consider C.

```
int * ptr = malloc(100);
free(ptr);
```

This C code works, even though we don't have to remind the compiler how big our array of ints was.

(Edit: To clarify that we're talking about deletion-time here. The compiler knows more at creation time than at deletion time. The question is "how does the system know, at deletion time, how much memory to delete?". One answer is at http://c-faq.com/malloc/freesize.html)

Answer (score 3):

It is no memory leak here, because program *knows* size of `temp`. Compiler substitute templated params with actual types in compile time, so when program runs it exactly knows type of `temp`

Comment: Actually, the compiler often doesn't know the size. But it doesn't need to know the size. It's a question of how memory is handled at a lower level. For example, if `T* temp = new U();` where U extends T, then `delete temp;` doesn't know whether it's dealing with a T or a U.

Comment: The fact that you should not explicitly tell the size of pointed object whene `delete`-ing does not mean that compiler can work without knwing size. Compiler _have to know_ size to _allocate_ memory for object.

Comment: The question is asking about deletion, and asking how the deletion code can 'know' the size. The question does not ask how the creation knows the size.

Comment: No! Why do you think so? Question is actually sort of 'how templates work': I think, author would not give us code with templates, if he had problem with understanding 'how delete work'

Comment: I don't think the questioner really knows what question they're asking. I still can't see any connection between templates and this question. Perhaps templates would be more relevant if there was not any `new` or `delete` and instead if `temp` was a value of type `T`, not `T*`, on the stack. Do you see what I'm getting at?

Comment: This following example would also work correctly, even though the compiler is quite ignorant of the true type: `T * temp = new T();
char * ptr = (char*) temp; delete ptr;`  Of course, the destructor wouldn't be called and this could lead to further problems (including a leak elsewhere). But there won't be a problem with freeing the memory which *temp was stored at.

Comment: With templates `T` type seems something 'abstract'. And T may be `int` or `char`, for example. That's why for the first time it can be not clear how to get known  size of `T` in `new T()`. Smth like this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5941/discussion-between-aaron-mcdaid-and-lol4t0)